# MS Excel - use the flexible sheet name in formulas reffering to sheet names

Tags: excel

I have honestly searched the topics already there, found a few with "Inderect" function, yet, can't come up with the way to use it for my task. Here's the task: There are sheets for each day of the month where employees log in their performance reports (digits only). Then there's a total performance page, where we get the monthly stats - this one works like a charm. Yet another page is for getting their payroll calculated. Payrol is calculated on "per week performance" basis. So, I need their performance for week one, week two and so on. As we all know, Mondays of the first week (for example) can be different dates from October 1st to October 6th. Since there are 8 employees, 4-5 weeks in a month, 6 workdays every week, with four different performance indicators, the matrix becomes something pain-in-the-{blank} to change formulas every month and has an enourmous chance for errors.
So, I would need a way to simply lay out the month in "This Month" area (see screenshot). Say AE30 cell contains "3", means this month's first Monday is 3rd of October, so the formula for employee's performance would read a cell from the sheet with name "3", for next month first Monday will be 1st, I'll give AE30 cell value of "1" and the formula for performance would read date from the sheet named "1". How do I do this? How do I change formulae in B4 (and other) cells to incorporate the sheet number from AB30 cell? Thank you!
[Link to screenshot](https://yadi.sk/i/E_RpqHYAwBKeM)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use INDIRECT with CONCATANATE -

```
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(A1,"!",B1))
```

Where in `A1` you got the name of the sheet (i.e "1"), and on `B1` you have the cell location.

Alternatively if you know where the data is on the source sheet (let's say A1)

```
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(A1,"!A1"))
```

If you want the data to be in reference to the destination cell, you can use ROW() and COLUMN().

Comment: Thank you very MUCH, IdanK! You helped me to solve the problem I had every month for few years by now!